# Is it useful to close ancient questions as too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In review I came upon several ancient questions (several years old) that were flagged as "too broad" - am I right in thinking this is just a waste of time/reviews and hence skipping them?

for instance

https://askubuntu.com/review/close/534275
https://askubuntu.com/review/close/533658
https://askubuntu.com/review/close/534340

Comment: @muru different questions IMO.

Comment: @Seth only by the close reason - both are for old questions getting closed, right?

Comment: And it was my own question too :-/ --- I guess its just when I hit a bunch of those I seem to get sort of angry ;-)

Comment: @guntbert damn. I didn't even notice it was by you. :D The only reason I remembered it was because I answered it.